# Drop down jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

http://jsfiddle.net/e36Xj/41/ I want the stylized dropdown to have a link on each when selected. upon select it will go to url. I temporary hide the other dropdown to avoid confusion.

```
  <select id="source" >
        <option selected="selected" value="BR">Brasil</option>
        <option value="FR">France</option>
        <option value="DE">Germany</option>
        <option value="IN">India</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear.

Comment: its not clear what you want to do

Comment: Are you trying to add and remove `option` tags?

Comment: Just add a link like VALUE="http:website"> based on the link provided

Comment: Edited the question. if any one can confirm will surely help.

Comment: the dropdown on the link provided create a script that dynamically create list from SELECT: but wish it will go to certain url upon selecting certain values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/e36Xj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e36Xj/44/)

Add below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {

        window.open($(this).find("span.value").html());
    });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the time buti just want to add a link to the values

Comment: maybe like onChange="go()"

Comment: Did the reference link helped? If so lets clean up the question and answer so that any rookie can understand the answer and save time OR Edit the jsfiddle link with your solution so one can understand it.

Comment: based on this http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/e36Xj/ wish upon selecting it will jump to certain url

Comment: adding onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO" doesnt work with this

Comment: I have updated the solution link correctly now. It was pointing to problem link earlier.

Comment: Can your please be more specific on the questions? See just because question is  ambiguous we are not able to solve this

Comment: in jsfiddle.net/prodac/e36Xj there is 2 dropdownon one is plain and the other is stylized (brown color), I want the stylized dropdown to have a link on each selection. upon select it will go to url.

Comment: i hide the other dropdown to avoid confusion, i want this stylize dropdown to have a link http://jsfiddle.net/e36Xj/41/

Comment: Here you go w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp